# Many web/ios/android apps connecting to the same Laravel Passport authentification

Tags: laravel, authentication, oauth, laravel-passport

I have a Laravel project with a passport api. I want my other websites to connect to this same authentification. In the future, even ios and android apps can authentify too. How can i set my other laravel projets to use this api oauth? Can i guard my pages with it?

Before doing anything i want to know if this is possible or if there is a better idea of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Yes, this is possible!

Long answer:

Passport provides OAuth2 which is the very same authentication protocol used by Sign in with Facebook and sing in with GitHub etc.

So your app with Passport is the user provider and your other apps are consumers. In the case of the consumers any OAuth2 client will do the trick (as long as you can create a custom provider for your Passport "server" app).

Laravel got your back with that too with: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/socialite. You can create a custom provider for your Passport "server" app.

TL;DR: Just like you would implement "Sign in with GitHub" (if you did that before) you can implement "Sign in with my Passport app" by writing your custom OAuth2 provider.

I cannot show much code since this will be highly specific but I do hope my story helps you find the correct packages/articles on how exactly to do this for your use case!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I added socialite, now i need to create a custom provider, not sure how. Do you have a guide?

Comment: I would suggest you take a look at how the other providers are implemented. You could for instance check out: https://github.com/SocialiteProviders/Providers or check out the built-in providers: https://github.com/laravel/socialite/tree/690c46cb572fb2f8a1a5520ff4b2446406ce5afd/src/Two

Comment: I set up everything, when i login from my client website, it redirect to my passport login. I log and i get this error every time : {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Client authentication failed","message":"Client authentication failed"}

Comment: That can have a lot of reasons. Maybe a good idea to put your implementation on the Laravel Forum to see if people can help you debug. Since I think this might be a configuration error.